# type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<string>'.Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<string>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, autocomplete, material-ui

```js
<Autocomplete
  value={value}
  onChange={(event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  }}
  inputValue={inputValue}
  onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
    setInputValue(newInputValue);
  }}
  id="controllable-states-demo"
  options={options}
  style={{ width: 300 }}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Controllable" variant="outlined" />}
/>
```

Please, help me out, I am new to typescript... In the below image you will see the error.

Thankyou.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, `newValue` can be either a string or null. It requires a string, so you should test the value of `newValue`  before you try to use it.

For example:

```
 if newValue !== nil {
   setValue(newValue)
 }
```